# Adding constrains to data inserted in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that is represented in [this ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NB7d.png). I want to add a constrain when I create ConcertSongs table that says: 'Don't allow adding songs to a concert whose band did not sing this song'. How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What I am thinking of is to handle that every single time I insert data to ConcertSongs table. But I am asking if there is a way to handle that just one time when we create the table.

Comment: Nope, you cannot do this with a constraint because the information is in a different table. No constraint can span multiple tables.

Comment: Are there any other ways that solve the problem?

Comment: A trigger would work.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to input by relating song to band do this:

```
INSERT INTO ConcertSongs (SongID, ConcertID) SELECT AlbumSOngs.SongID, Concert.ConcertID WHERE ConcertSongs.SongID = AlbumSongs.SongID AND AlbumSongs.AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID;
```

If you are relating to concert ID also then you will need to Alias in a CASE like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, etc. (case when (state1 = '' and state2 = '') 
 THEN
      //new SQL 
 ELSE
      //SQL 
 END)
 as state from table;
```

Depending on how you complicated your tables i advice adding new columns to use for relating them to each other, this would decrease SQL run time, and make it easier for you.